# Probabilistic time algorithm for finding the solution for quadratic congruences (case when p is prime)

Tags: algorithms, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, quadratic-residues

I was trying to solve the following equation:

$$y = x^2 \bmod p$$

where $p$ is prime.

I was trying to find an algorithm that solved this and that was in BPP (I don't think there is one in P). I know it exists so an explanation of the algorithm or a link to somewhere it is explained would be great!

If someone knows the name of these algorithms it would be great! (its easier to google them or look for them)

Comment: I changed y = x^2 \ ( \ mod \ p) to y = x^2 \pmod p.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard algorithms (Cipolla or Tonelli-Shanks) are in BPP. The only probabilistic part in those algorithms is to find a quadratic non-residue mod $p$, this succeeds with probability only $\frac{p-1}{2p}$, but the probability can be made arbitrarily low by just making enough random picks, which doesn't hurt the polynomial running time. The Wikipedia articles on those algorithms are not very good; I especially like [the book of Crandall and Pomerance](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/numbers/book/978-0-387-25282-7) for such topics.

Wikipedia links:
en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cipolla%27s_algorithm 
en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli-Shanks_algorithm

Comment: Do you have a source were I could read it free online? Or do u know them? What is the name for the algorithm, do you know?

Comment: Also, do any of them use the legendre symbol to find the solutions?

Comment: You can always check Wikipedia, and the references listed at the bottom of the articles, which include some online PDFs. The algorithms use the Legendre symbol only to check that the chosen value is a quadratic non-residue. Once a non-residue has been found, the Legendre symbol is not used anymore (and the algorithm from then on is deterministic).

Comment: Do you know the names of these algorithms, so that I could look them up in the book or wikipedia? Is it Cipolla algorithm?

Comment: Yes. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cipolla%27s_algorithm http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli-Shanks_algorithm

Comment: Wikipedia implies that Tonelli–Shanks is a better algorithm (because its less redundant), what do you think? (btw thanks!)

Comment: Also, if your university has a subscription to the Springer e-book collection, the book of Crandall and Pomerance can be accessed for free. Try visiting springerlink.com from an on-campus machine.

Comment: The article on Cipolla's algorithm says "Cipolla's algorithm is better than the Tonelli-Shanks algorithm if and only if $S(S-1) > 8m+20$, with $2^{S}$ being the maximum power of $2$ which divides $p-1$." ($m$ being the size of $p$, so about $\log p$.)